# Multisig storage showing calls from another one

Tags: frame, multisig

I figured there seem to be something wrong with a multisig I have on Rococo.

It's this one: 5FRz8z6U87LBXLUuBRRy4JtVAh2jhkDSbR5ntCGM2Ds631dJ

Checking the storage on it with `multisig.multisigs("5FRz8z6U87LBXLUuBRRy4JtVAh2jhkDSbR5ntCGM2Ds631dJ")` returns the following double map:

```
  [
    [
      5G7yHTYnAJKQ6RLe6woPrcrNRdnPtzEuZNjNDvhLVD8eZAqL
      0xe133e6f11af51d883e56216e9e1bbb1e2920c7c6120cbb55cd469b1f95b61601
    ]
    {
      when: {
        height: 3,833,859
        index: 2
      }
      deposit: 67,173,327,600
      depositor: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
      approvals: [
        5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

However, as you can tell, this storage is for `5G7yHTYnAJKQ6RLe6woPrcrNRdnPtzEuZNjNDvhLVD8eZAqL` which is another multisig.

How is this possible?

edit:

I have another such call for `5Hr2iNQ3HvsyAS1Ni5oX2XuXAAPyNGZ68UkaQPRnFZrY5FUk` that is given a multisig call from `5FhVnBbhiswx58VjLgN9bB8tuu4NpYALLfWzcRTUkPNSyVf5`. Just see it for yourself, go to pjs/apps > dev > chain state and query the `multisig.multisigs` with this account. Although this multisig is actually 5 days old, you'll see a call in storage from 6 months ago.

edit2: This seems linked to a bug reported in polkadot-js apps https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9103 .

Comment: The account_id you are using to query is the account_id of the multisig? which addresses are the list of address of the multisig?

Comment: Yes it's a multisig composed of 2/3 by
- 5DqVySMC366P8NRjdyp948TJj64hAvg17eaiEn4ZbuKCNZHc
- 5DqgU9eK7Jdtc4wfozYMdy5pFtyupnfethvLZ15fgiTZDnkM
- 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there seems to be an issue with the node. Should be fixed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13630) and the reporting PolkadotJS issue is [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9103).